# How to recognize overflow bugs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I spent part of yesterday and today tracking down a bug in some Matlab code.  I had thought my problem was indexing (with many structures that I didn't define and am still getting used to), but it turned out to be an overflow bug.  I missed this for a very specific reason:

```
>> uint8(2) - uint8(1)

ans =

    1

>> uint8(2) - uint8(2)

ans =

    0

>> uint8(2) - uint8(3)

ans =

    0
```

I would have expected the last one to be something like `-1` (or `255`).  In the middle of a big vector, the erroneous `0`s were difficult to detect, but a `255` would have stood out easily.

Any tips on how to detect these problems easily in the future?  (Ideally, I'd like to turn off the overflow checking to make it work like C.)  Changing to `double` works, of course, but if I don't realize it's a `uint8` to begin with, that doesn't help.

Comment: Where do you get these numbers from? If you load them from file, you can simply add a line to the loader to either return all as uint8, or as double.
Other than by reading files you should not expect uint8's in Matlab.

Comment: I actually don't really know exactly where they're coming from.  I'm integrating with someone else's code, so I don't know the details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can start by turning on integer warnings:

```
intwarning('on')
```

This will give you a warning when integer arithmetic overflows.

Beware though, as outlined [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/intwarning.html), this does slow down integer arithmetic so only use this during debug.

Comment: Note: [INTWARNING has now been removed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bsdgysw-1.html#bseu09o-1), and the link above is now invalid.

Comment: Do you guys know why it was removed and what to use instead?

Answer (score 6):

Starting with release R2010b and later, the function [INTWARNING has been removed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bsdgysw-1.html#bseu09o-1), along with [these warning messages for integer math and conversion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bsdgysw-1.html#bse_gbf-1):

- `MATLAB:intConvertNaN`
- `MATLAB:intConvertNonIntVal`
- `MATLAB:intConvertOverflow`
- `MATLAB:intMathOverflow`

So using INTWARNING is no longer a viable option for determining when integer overflows occur. An alternative is to use the [CLASS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/class.html) function to test the class of your data and recast it accordingly before performing the operation. Here's an example:

```
if strcmp(class(data),'uint8')  %# Check if data is a uint8
  data = double(data);          %# Convert data to a double
end
```

You could also use the [ISA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isa.html) function as well:

```
if ~isa(data,'single')  %# Check if data is not a single
  data = single(data);  %# Convert data to a single
end
```

Comment: If you do not know where your data is coming from, you should definitely do very careful input testing like this.

Comment: @gnovice I just ran into the same problem, but your approach of casting to double or single seems very weird to me. What if I need those uints? I don't want to be forced to do everything on doubles. Not a question to you of course, but why can't MATLAB use standard unsigned integer operations?

Answer (score 1):

See INTWARNING function to control warnings on integer operations.

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/intwarning.html

Comment: Note: [INTWARNING has now been removed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bsdgysw-1.html#bseu09o-1), and the link above is now invalid.